# Setting correct permissions after Windows reinstall

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-permissions

I have had to reinstall Windows on my laptop, I installed Windows without formatting because I had my data files and folder on there including on the root folder for example C:\my_projects etc

Now as I have installed new OS win 7, when I open up these folder I get permission errors, these project folders have very very deep structure and contain numerous files.

When I check permissions at the top of the folder it shows lot of Account Unknown items in the Groups and users. Furthermore the ownership of folder is Unknown when seen from the advance permissions.

So the question is how do I change these permissions/security/ownership at the top level without doing it for sub folders so that I have access back to my folders and it is more like default folders and also I remove those unknown user entries from all subfolders/files.

Answer (score 0):

#### when I open up this folder (C:\my_projects) I get permission errors

You need to take ownership of the directory.

Note:

- Do **not** take ownership of `C:\`.

  Doing so, could result in Windows becoming very unstable.

Use one of the following commands from an elevated command prompt.

**To grant ownership to currently logged on user**:

```
takeown /F "C:\my_projects" /R /D Y
```

**To set any user as owner**:

```
icacls "C:\my_projects" /setowner "user name" /T /C
```

---

#### Take Ownership of an Object using TAKEOWN Command

This command will take ownership of the folder or drive, and all files and subfolders in the folder or drive.

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To grant ownership to currently logged on user:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /R /D Y
```

To grant ownership to the administrators group:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /A /R /D Y
```

Examples:

```
takeown /F "F:" /A /R /D Y
takeown /F "F:\Folder" /A /R /D Y
```

---

#### Take Ownership of a Folder or Drive and All Contents using ICALCS Command

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To set any user as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "user name" /T /C
```

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Example:

```
icacls "C:\Windows\Folder" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Source [Take Ownership of a File, Folder, Drive, or Registry Key in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html)